# Intermittent NoMemoryError in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

We have a Ruby rails runner script that loads a bunch of JSON schema files, processes them, and writes the processed data to files.

If I run the rails runner script repeatedly, it raises **failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)** once every 15-20 times. I've compared the memory usages between the failed and successful runs before termination and both were ~178 MB. The VM has about ~ 2 GB of free memory.

Based on the log lines I've added for debugging, it's failing when the code does **JSON.pretty_generate(schema)**.

Observations:

1. The script is processing the same set of files and I don't understand why it raises **NoMemoryError** intermittently.
2. The script is processing the files in the same order
3. In all the failed runs, it failed exactly when it was processing a particular file. I fired up IRB and tried to do the same set of operations with the file and measured the memory usage before and after these operations. It resulted in a memory increase of only ~100 KB.
4. I tried raising **RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS**, so that the process memory size is 10x more than the successful or failed runs but still no luck. There are lots and lots of **heap_free_slots** (54x **heap_live_slots**) when it raises NoMemoryError

Here are the questions that I have:

1. Why doesn't Ruby get more memory allocated even when there's around ~2GB of free memory in the VM?
2. Any pointers or suggestions?

Ruby version: 2.7.1
Rails version: 5.2.4.2

Thank you!

Comment: My coworker found a workaround. He added an extra character to that particular JSON file and we didn't see "NoMemoryError" out of the 200+ runs that we did. No clue or explanation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We narrowed it down to the Oj gem. The following commit fixed the issue.

https://github.com/ohler55/oj/commit/f026333afed8c3ecda4978d41914dd5a424cb995#diff-99f7fc0c2799095139bbbfb7b553ce81c0c6edcbc3b2f6b729bb26d052b8ed6d